# Reading large HDF using with Fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5, hierarchical-data, chunking, large-data

I have some HDF data that has been created with [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/). This data is very large, an array of 3973850000 x 8 double precision values, but with PyTables compression this can easily be stored.

I want to access this data using Fortran. I do,

```
PROGRAM HDF_READ
USE HDF
IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER(LEN=100), PARAMETER :: filename = 'example.h5'
CHARACTER(LEN=100), PARAMETER :: dsetname = 'example_dset.h5'
INTEGER error
INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id
INTEGER(HID_T) :: dset_id
INTEGER(HID_T) :: space_id
INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(2) :: data_dims, max_dims
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: dset_data


!Initialize Fortran interface
CALL h5open_f(error)

!Open an existing file
CALL h5open_f(filename, H5F_ACC_RDONLY_F, file_id,error)
END PROGRAM HDF_READ

!Open a dataset
CALL h5dopen_f(file_id, dsetname, dset_id, error)

!Get dataspace ID
CALL h5dget_space_f(dset_id, space_id, error)

!Get dataspace dims
CALL h5sget_simple_extent_dims_f(space_id, data_dims,max_dims, error)

!Create array to read into
ALLOCATE(dset_data(data_dims(1), data_dims(2)))


!Get the data
CALL h5dread_f(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, dset_data, data_dims,error)
```

However, this creates an obvious problem, in that the array cannot be allocated to such a large size with double precision floats as it becomes greater than the system memory.

**What is the best method for accessing this data?** My current thoughts are for some sort of chunking method? Or is there a way to store the array on disk? Does HDF have methods for dealing with large data like this - I have read around but can find nothing pertaining to my case.

Comment: What do you need to do with your data? HDF5 is built for accessing chunks of data at a time, but if you plan to use all the information concurrently...

Comment: For each row in the dataset I need to inspect it and see if it satisfies some mathematical criteria, so chunking is fine

Comment: You need to use the routine `h5sselect_hyperslab_f` https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5S.html#Dataspace-SelectHyperslab I suggest to load data by blocks that are multiples of the chunksize if available, else it is up to you what amount of data to load at a time. You can check the storage chunking with the command-line tool h5dump as `h5dump -A -p myfile.h5` (with optionally `-g /mygroup` or `-d /my/dataset` to focus on the group/dataset of interest)